# How to make django aware of templates directory?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am trying to follow tango with Django book and build Rango app, but now I am not sure how to make django aware of my templates' directory:

Views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 

def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold"} 
    return render_to_response('/rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Amir")
```

Settings.py:

```
import os

SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join( SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join( PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))



SECRET_KEY = 't0qwy81#5-jd(wtxqp$6_p%@l@lthq5qyb-35vyp=g+h!k+h+n'


DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'rango',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RangoTango.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RangoTango.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

TEMPLATE_DIR = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Error:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    127-0-0-1
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
/rango/index.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but you shouldn't have a leading `/` on the template name in the call to `render_to_response `.

Comment: I solved it myself by moving the static folder to my application folder.

Comment: @JustLeraning - could you post that as an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the folder to my app folder to make it work